# Using camera and table cell SWIFT

Tags: xcode, swift, camera

I would like to be able to have a camera button where I can take a picture and it saves to a table cell. When I click the table cell i want the image to fill the screen. I am new to this and I would like to know if this can be done. If it can does anyone know how to help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is basically what instagram does, when you take a picture it displays to a tableview cell. This is an easy tutorial to get you started; http://www.appcoda.com/instagram-app-parse-swift/

edit: skip the parse part if you dont want to upload the pictures to a server.